# Not getting internet when multiple devices are connected to router when connecting for first time

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I have a netgear router. I use cable internet, provided by local cable operator. Inorder for me to get internet connectivity, i have to first login to their portal and then only internet becomes active. Till then the connection will be displayed as "Limitied Connectivitiy"

Problem is, when i try to access internet for first time(i.e., when login is required), if both my laptop and mobile's wifi is enabled, they will be connected to the router's wifi network(as expected), but am not able to connect to internet then. Not even able to get the login page through either device.

The only work around i have found is, to switch everything off, and keep either mobile or laptop WIFI only ON, and then turn the router back on. Then login to the portal, make sure internet is working. Then onwards i can add any number of devices to the router and they will start working.

Not sure whats wrong, but it kinda looks like IP assigning problem from the router.

Anyone has faced this before? Any solutions?
Can give the router details and settings if required.

TIA
Cyriac George

Answer (score 0):

If login is required when you access the internet, it means you use PPPoE authentification or VPN. That means only one device will actually have access at the same time. If this is the case (for PPPoE), your router must be configured normally (NAT mode), not in bridge mode. The router should connect and login with user and password and all other devices should get local IP addresses from the router, without logging in.
If that portal is a VPN gateway, then it will give you another IP address at authentification, and that will be your WAN IP. This would complicate things because the router configuration above is no longer possible too easy.

Comment: Unless he's using wireless router to split his LAN connection for which he's required to authenticate via HTTP website. Which would explain his issues as server may block multiple devices on same IP. I'd say "Contact your ISP as this is config/credentials/restrictions issue".

Comment: ISP may not be his own, but to a 3rd party that he connects to.

Comment: He writes when he connects to the internet he needs to enter credentials via HTTP interface. Just like Starbucks... Unless I'm missing something that's his ISP.